# The word underlying

Tags: word-usage

What meaning does the word "underlying" add in this sentence?

> Behaviorism is based on a number
>   of **underlying** assumptions regarding methodology and behavioral
>   analysis: Psychology should be seen as a science.

"Underlying" means "true causes" but assumptions are the things which are not proved.
So it doesn't make a sense for me. Is it like true lies?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Underlying* **may** mean ‘true cause’, but it does not **have** to mean that. What it means here is simply that the assumptions in some sense ‘lie under’ the discourse of behaviorists: probably that the assumptions are not made explicit but lie deep ‘beneath’ the surface discourse, perhaps so deep that they are not even recognized as assumptions by the behaviorists themselves.

Comment: Thank you I think I got it @StoneyB..Could you please explain what you mean by the discourse of behaviorist. which sense did you use the word discourse in this sentence?

Comment: @Murat Their writing and speech - or what they say in writing or speech.